# How can I handle messages that are not matched in any subscription filter?

Tags: servicebus

I know that you can prevent messages from being published to a topic when there are no matching subscribers (with the `TopicDescription.EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing` setting).

But I don't want to make it a problem of the publisher when there is no subscriber. I would like the message to be dead-lettered or otherwise received in a subscription with an 'if nothing else matched' filter.

Comment: Not sure how to do that elegantly, but you could set up a subscription without a filter that would receive all messages. Then activate the option "Enable dead lettering on message expiration" and a suitable time-to-live value for the messages. Then if no other subscription processed the message before expiry, it'd end up dead lettered. I can think of various reasons why you wouldn't want such a setup, but just an idea.